# Xamarin.Build.Download Error

Tags: xamarin.android

I just updated the packages of nuget and, I m getting this error in my application even though i have Xamarin.Build.Download 0.4.11.
It says the missing file in packages is Xamarin.Build.Download 0.4.7.
The only solution i found was to downgrade the version of this.
Are there any other solutions that helps me work on 0.4.11?

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ..\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.7\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.props.  RoutineApp  C:\some path
>   Studio 2017\some app 411

Comment: Does this error happen in a blank project?

Comment: no it happened in a running project i updated and found the current error even though i downgraded to solve the issue but i'd like to work on updated packages @BillyLiu-MSFT